# I'm trying to pass an array from controller to javascript by using ajax but it doesnt return as array it returns as a String

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Here is my code from controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{

    public function showOrder($id){
        $result = DB::select('select * from menu_tbl where id = ?', array($id));
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Here is my code from javascript:

```js
function addOrder(id){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/showOrder/"+id,
        success: function (data){
            alert(data["name"] + " " + data);

            //document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data['name'];
            //document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data['price'];
            //$("#buying").modal();
        },
    });
}
```

Here is the result:

```js
undefined [{"id":1,"name":"Chicken Cordon Bleu","category":"chicken","price":800,"description":"blah blah","img":"img\/mcdonalds-burger.jpg","hot":0,"spicy":0}]
```

the `data['name']` returns as `undefined` is there something wrong in my code? or the `DB:select` doesn't return array instead a String. I'm new at Laravel. Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Edit your question and post your code instead of photo

Comment: Please post code directly in the question, opening links to read code snippets is off-putting.

Comment: just do `JSON.parse(data)` in javascript part of the application

Comment: as i see, data is array of object, so have you tried to access array like this: data[0].name

Comment: i did the data[0] it returns the "["

Comment: i did the JSON.parse(data) it returns as [object, Object][

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code as below.

```
 public function showOrder($id){
        $result = DB::table('menu_tbl')->where('id',$id)->first();
        return \Response::json($result);

    }
```

jquery as below.

```
success: function (data){
        alert(data.name);
},
```

Comment: yay it worked xD can i ask where did i go wrong in the code?

Comment: never mind i found my mistake xD the json_encoder() was wrong the \Response::json or response()->json() was the right thing hahha

Comment: json_encode also right one. but for that you have to parse json. @Krzysztof Krzeszewski suggest you in comment

Comment: yes i saw your comment and i even respond to it it returns "[objecjt Object]"